# How to convert char to an array of bits in c++?

Tags: c++

I need to get each Character of a string as a sequence of bits either in an array or just traverse over it in a loop, either way works. This is something I used to do in ASM way back, and am not sure how that can be done in c++.

EDIT: I am trying to replicate what I did sometime back with asm, reading a file in memory and traversing it bit by bit, manipulate each bit, do some more cyphering and save it back.

Basically a simple Encryption. Its not a homework neither it is a project.

Comment: @user93353 nothing :) Don't have slightest of idea how to go about it.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: `std::bitset` has a constructor that accepts `std::string`.

Comment: @JohnDibling Homework, possibly.

Comment: @user93353:  Perhaps, but I doubt it, and even if it were homework, officially that's OK.  You can choose not to answer homework questions, but people are not forbidden from asking them.  In any case, it's irrelevant if this is homework.  StudentX is posing an XY problem, where they are trying to accomplish X by doing Y and asking how to do Y, where the interesting question is "what is X?"

Comment: @JohnDibling - never said it's forbidden to ask homework questions. However from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) - `Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.`

Comment: @user93353: I agree with your link, but it bears no relation to any reason why you would have replied with the comment, "Homework, possibly."

Comment: @JohnDibling - Your question `What are you really trying to do?`. In a homework question - there may not be a question behind the question. i.e. no `what are you really trying to do?`. Anyway, enough from my side in this.

Comment: but a char already is a sequence of bits.  if you're using c++, i think it's 8 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate through it using bit operators:

```
unsigned char c = 'a'
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  std::cout << (c >> i) & 1 << std::endl;
}
```

This will shift `c` to the right for `i` position, and use bitwise AND to get value of the least significant bit.

Answer (score 6):

The Standard Library has a class for that, [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/). It may be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look using a bit-mask and bit-wise operators `&`, `|`, `>>` and/or maybe `<<`.  I'm guessing that you'll want to store them in an array of bool type, something like `bool bitArray[256];`

Of course it is standard practice to just use `unsigned char` for storing a bunch of bits.

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop over the character and check the bits with a bitmask

```
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    bool is_set = c & (1 << i);
    std::out << "Bit " << i << ": " << is_set << '\n';
}
```

or a string

```
std::string s;
for (auto p = s.begin(); p != s.end(); ++p) {
    char c = *p;
    // loop over the bits
}
```